# SSO SAML in Spring - supporting dynamic Multi-Tenant settings

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml

I am new to SAML
I currently have a Spring Restful web server application which use spring security with Basic Authentication.
Since I have multiple enterprise customers i would like to support SAML SSO.

Trying to find documentation and preferably examples of how to set up SAML to authenticate with different IDPs for different customers, where the SAML IDP details are read from a persistence layer (DB).

Also would like to know the strategy for supporting the right login in the web application. Would i need now to support different URLs for each customer, so i know against which IDP to authenticate against?

For example I have two customers

Customer A - uses SAML IDP server A'

Customer B - uses SAML IDP server B'

When customer A's user gets to my site:
how would i know that now i need to authenticated against SAML IDP A'?
is it by the url, or some url parameter?
Once i know who he is, how do i setup spring saml to authenticate with IDP A' (read that from the DB settings for that customer). Notice i cant pre-set the IDPs in the spring configuration, as new customers can join later with new IDP.

thanks

Comment: Exact requirement what I have at the moment and this is the first time I am assigned anything on the security module and I wander through these documentations on SAML, oAuth2, OpenID etc.